# Remove element from XML file using php when i need only certain ones

Tags: php, xml

I know the title might seem a little strange and I apologize in advance, but i want to be able to do this:

the xml file looks like this:

```
<data>
<row>
    <EventID>12345</EventID>
    <Event>Name of Event</Event>
    <EventCat>2</PCatID>
    <City>Tacoma</City>
    <State>Washington</State>
    <Zip>98421</Zip>
</row>
```

now there are a ton of these with different category ID's (lets say 1-5) I want to be able to just save the ones with category 2 and delete the rest. any ideas?  I have been on here and saw a couple of different examples but couldn't get them to work.

like this one:

```
$searchString = '1';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$doc->load($path.'name.xml');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = sprintf('//data/row[./PCatID[text()="%s"]]', $searchString);
}
$doc->saveXML();
```

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for those rows with XPath and remove them:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadXml($f);
$xp = new DOMXpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//row[./PCatID != 2]") as $ev) {
    $ev->parentNode->removeChild($ev);
}
```

Comment: but that will remove the whole "row" not just the PCatID node right?

Comment: $file_xml = $path."name.xml";
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->load($file_xml);
$xp = new DOMXpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//row[./PCatID != 2]") as $ev) {
    $ev->parentNode->removeChild($ev); 
}
$d->save($file_xml);

Comment: @user Sure. Wasn't that what you wanted? In any case, if you only wanted to remove the `PCatID` element it would only be a small change to the xpath expression.

Comment: Yea thats exactly what I wanted. just dont see any changes when i place this code on the php file.  also $f is the absolute path to the XML file right?

Comment: and what about $d->saveXml(); is that actually needed as well? i would presume so right? sorry for the novice questions. I have never done this xml type stuff before.

Comment: so looking at my error log i see: DOMDocument::loadXML() [<a href='domdocument.loadxml'>domdocument.loadxml</a>]: Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1 -------- then it says  line 8 which is $d->loadXml($file_xml); and $file_xml is the absolute path to the xml file. arggg.  sorry to be such a pain man. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers above seems solid, It really didnt work for me. Finally I got what I needed to work by doing the following:

```
<?php
$path = 'absolute/server/path';
$file_xml = $path."/your/xml/file.xml";
$data = simplexml_load_file($file_xml);
$data_count = count($data->row);
for($i = 0; $i < $data_count; $i++)
{
//basically what you want to remove
if( ($data->row[$i]->PCatID == "1") || ($data->row[$i]->PCatID == "3") || ($data->row[$i]->PCatID == "4") )
{
    unset($data->row[$i]);
}
}
file_put_contents($file_xml, $data->saveXML());
?>
```

So in this case please see above for the information for "row", "PCatID"